# Assuming direct-mapping cache, how is LDR handled in the following cases?

Tags: caching, assembly, pipeline

I've been tasked to make a "timing" table for the following code (using a 5-stage pipeline):

```
LDR R1, = 0x345678
LDR R2, [R1]
LDR R3, =0xFC167B
LDR R4, [R3]
LDR R5, =0xD8967A
LDR R6, [R5]
```

Assuming these are all "cache misses", I am wondering where delays would be introduced if we are assuming a 1-cycle penalty in the event of a miss. My thoughts are that the first line, `LDR R1, = 0x345678`, wouldn't cause a penalty, since are just loading some word into a register.

But for the second line, `LDR R2, [R1]`, I am thinking that there *will* be a penalty, since we are trying to read from the cache, but it isn't *in* the cache. Hence, would there just be a delay after the "Memory" stage of the pipeline?

Regards

Comment: `LDR R1, =0x345678` isn't a real pseudo-op, it's changed by the assembler into something of the form `LDR R1, [PC, #1234]`. So it also has to read memory. There's small chance it's close enough the instruction that its on the same cache line as the instruction and so in the cache (assuming a unified L1 cache), but it's not likely. More likely is that the next two LDR= pseudo-instructions will read from the same cache line as the first one, but its not guaranteed.

Comment: So... That is to mean that in the "memory" portion of the pipeline, the first, third, and fifth lines will all have a delay?

Comment: I don't know how your pipeline works. I only know that first, third and fifth instructions are actually something like `LDR R1, [PC, #1234]`, `LDR R3, [PC, #1230]` and `LDR R5, [PC, #1226]`, each reading a different memory location somewhere within +/- 4K of the code.